# validar 24 horas rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
validate :prueba

def prueba
  self.hora_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )

  if ( hora_entre - ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) < ( hora_pedido )
    errors.add(:hora_entre, "hora  no válida")
  end
end
```

**validar**

`hora_entre` se escoge por formulario y `hora_pedido` por `self` 
si no,  que no me da,  quiero validar si es menor de **24 Horas** y me salga error.

hora_entrega es hora_entre

**Log**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se ve error evidente en tu código, ¿te muestra algún error en el log o cuál es el comportamiento que tienes (y no debería tener)?

Comment: si no que no valida

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el log que genera?

Comment: Solo para clarificar la lógica: ¿Quieres mostrar error si la diferencia entre `hora_entrega` y `hora_pedido` es menor a 24 hrs? O mejor dicho, ¿`hora_entrega` debe ser mayor a `hora_pedido` por 24hrs o más?

Comment: hola  si estas en lo cierto @Gerry. gracias

Comment: Ok, entonces si será necesario ver el log para saber porque falla.

Comment: ya la actualice gracia @Gerry.

Comment: Parece ser que la validación si está funcionando, posiblemente no estés mostrando el mensaje correctamente en tu vista. ¿Podrías mostrar el código de la vista donde muestras el error? Y, ¿podrías poner `save!` temporalmente en tu acción `create` y actualizar el log con lo que se muestre en consola?

Comment: ya la actualice gracia @Gerry

Comment: La validaciones sí están funcionando, lo puedes ver claramente en el log, ahí muestra los mensajes que estas validaciones generaron al fallar. Esos mensajes (o el primero, dependiendo como lo hayas determinado en tu vista) se deben de mostrar en la vista `new`. Si no los ves entonces tu vista es la que debe ser corregida.

Comment: como debe de ir en la vista @Gerry? gracias.

Comment: hola @Gerry  puedes  ver por que no funciona maestro detalle.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60858/discussion-between-gerry-and-juan-gomez).

Comment: en dos horas,  es  que en el momento no puedo.@Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar los errores en tu vista, debes buscar si hay errores que se hayan generado en el objeto (e.g. `@reunion`) y, en caso que así sea, desplegarlos en tu vista.

Por ejemplo, en tu vista `new.html.erb` podrías agregar el siguiente código<sup>1</sup>:

```
<% if @reunion.errors.any? %>
  <div>
    Se han encontrado los siguientes errores:
    <ul>
      <% @reunion.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Debes definir el lugar en la página donde quieres que se muestre este mensaje (generalmente es en arriba del formulario) y estilizarlo de acuerdo al diseño de tu sitio.

<sup>1</sup> *Estoy asumiendo que el objeto que deseas crear se llama `@reunion`, pero sustituye la variable por la que esté definida en la acción `create` del controlador.*